# Exportar Tabela para Excel, problemas com String Numerica

Tags: php, string, microsoft-excel, int, exportação

procurei aqui no Stack, mas talvez não achei a pergunta certa, estou exportando dados do PHP para o Excel com tags HTML, ele exporta numa boa, acontece que tenho uma coluna que é String, por exemplo "89551010326000103872", mas o Excel insiste em transformar em numero acabando com meus dados veja "8,95510103260001E+19" eu tentei colocar (String)$Data pra forçar o uso de string, mas como esperava não adiantou

Uma linha da tabela é mais ou menos isso

```
...
<table> 
<tr>
<td>89551010326000103872 </td>
<td>CONTROLE</td>
</tr> 
</table> 
...
```

Será que tem alguma coisa que eu possa colocar no TD para o excel entender que é uma String e e não numero?

Answer (score 0):

Para escapar um número em uma célula como string, você pode colocar uma aspa simples no começo da célula, então ficaria assim:

```
...
<table> 
<tr>
<td>'89551010326000103872 </td>
<td>CONTROLE</td>
</tr> 
</table> 
...
```

Comment: Mas aí ele vai ficar com essa aspa no inicio do número, no meu caso não posso deixar assim.